# Dúvida com relação a array bidimensional Java

Tags: java

Tenho esse array bidimensional e queria criar um objeto diferente para cada indice dele, porém estou com problemas para fazer isso com um `for`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

Predio predio = new Predio();

Predio predioArray[][];

System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Andares do Predio: ");
predio.setQtdAndares(scanner.nextInt());
System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Apartamentos do Predio: ");
predio.setQtdApartamentos(scanner.nextInt());

predioArray = new Predio[predio.getQtdAndares()][predio.getQtdApartamentos()];

for(Predio[] auxPr: predioArray) {

}
```

Chegando nessa parte eu travei, não sei como fazer esse `for` para incializar um objeto para cada índice desse array bidimensional (ou seja, iria fazer `system.out` para cada Andar ( Qual quantidade de predios no andar? ) e para Cada Apartamento (Qual a quantidade de quarto, cozinha, banheiro etc)).

Comment: Vc quer printar todos os andares e seus cômodos de todos os prédios?? E onde vc está definindo os cômodos de cada andar?

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, tente melhorar um pouco na questão da escrita para ficar mais fácil

Comment: @Gustavo sim eu ainda não defini isso na classe exatamente por que estou com dúvidas em como vou inicializar cada objeto para cada indice, ou seja o indice 0 seria o andar 0 ( esse andar 0, eu colocarei um scanner para o usuario definir quantos apartamentos vão existir nesse andar e assim por diante) no caso [andar] seria o meu indice.

Comment: @AndersonHenrique vou tentar modificar, mas basicamente eu só queria inicializar cada objeto para cada indice um exemplo: em um array normal,  Agenda aux = new Agenda(), Agenda a[] = new Agenda[5] e então eu faria um for  para incializar: For(int i = 0 ; i<a.length; i++){ a[i] = new Agenda();}

Comment: @JoaoSpirit Entendi. Caso um andar não tenha lavanderia, por exemplo, o seu `print` poderia mostra algo do tipo: "lavanderia = 0" ou quando não houver ele não deve mostrar?

Comment: @Gustavo poderia até não mostrar, eu consegui fazer algo parecido com isso mas com esse for normal dentro de outro for normal,  mas não consegui resolver isso fazendo um for aprimorado :( .

Comment: É só fazer um for dentro de outro for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua modelagem está meio... esquisita. Se a classe `Predio` representa um prédio, um array de `Predio` na verdade representa vários prédios (ou seja, uma rua, um quarteirão, um condomínio, ou algo assim).

Um array de alguma coisa serve para representar várias instâncias diferentes dessa coisa. Um array de prédios não deveria ser usado para representar um único prédio.

Sendo assim, esqueça o que está fazendo e volte para a prancheta. Se quer representar os andares e apartamentos do prédio, coloque esses dados dentro de um único prédio. E aí tem vários jeitos diferentes, dependendo do que precisa fazer.

Um exemplo seria ter uma classe para representar um apartamento. Aí você poderia ter um array de apartamentos dentro da classe `Predio`:

```
public class Predio {
    private Apartamento[] aptos;
}
```

E o apartamento poderia ter o número do andar, por exemplo (ou este poderia ser inferido a partir do número - ex: apto 135 está no décimo terceiro andar).

Esta é uma abordagem mais simples, já que os apartamentos ficariam todos no mesmo array e para saber quais ficam em um andar específico, teria que encontrar as posições exatas, seja fazendo algum cálculo (se todos os andares possuem a mesma quantidade de apartamentos, o cálculo é mais fácil), seja percorrendo o array até encontrar os apartamentos.

Claro que também poderia ser:

```
private Apartamento[][] aptos;
```

Assim, o primeiro índice indica o andar (`aptos[0]` é um array que contém os apartamentos do térreo, `aptos[1]` é um array que contém os aptos do primeiro andar, etc).

Se quiser complicar um pouco mais, poderia ter:

```
public class Andar {
    private Apartamentos[] aptos;
}

public class Predio {
    private Andar[] andares;
}
```

Caso o andar precise ter mais informações atreladas ao mesmo (sei lá, há prédios em que não há latas de lixo em todos os andares, então esta poderia ser uma informação da classe `Andar`). Mas se o andar não precisa ter nenhuma informação específica, então não vale a pena criar esta classe.

---

Outro ponto é que você leu a quantidade de andares e a quantidade **total** de apartamentos do prédio. Então você está assumindo que todos os andares possuem a mesma quantidade de apartamentos, e basta dividir o total pela quantidade de andares? E se o usuário digitar valores que não dão um valor exato?

Enfim, uma abordagem poderia ser usar o array de array de apartamentos, assumindo que todos os andares têm a mesma quantidade de apartamentos:

```
public class Predio {

    private Apartamento[][] aptos;

    public Predio(int qtdAndares, int aptosPorAndar) {
        this.aptos = new Apartamento[qtdAndares][aptosPorAndar];
    }

    public void adicionarApto(int andar, Apartamento apto) {
        if (andar >= this.aptos.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O prédio só tem " + this.aptos.length + " andares");
        }
        // encontra a primeira posição não preenchida
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this.aptos[andar].length && this.aptos[andar][i] != null)
            i++;
        if (i >= this.aptos[andar].length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Andar " + andar + " já está com todos os apartamentos cadastrados");
        }
        this.aptos[andar][i] = apto;
    }
}
```

E para ler os dados:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Andares do Predio: ");
int qtdAndares = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de Apartamentos por andar: ");
int aptosPorAndar = scanner.nextInt();
Predio predio = new Predio(qtdAndares, aptosPorAndar);
for (int andar = 0; andar < qtdAndares; andar++) {
    for (int apto = 0; apto < aptosPorAndar; apto++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o numero do apto");
        int numero = scanner.nextInt();
        // leia todos os dados que um apartamento precisa e passe todos para o construtor
        predio.adicionarApto(andar, new Apartamento(numero));
    }
}
```

Lembrando que neste caso, o andar zero (térreo) também conta. Então se o usuário digitar `20` para a quantidade de andares, o prédio terá os andares de 0 a 19.

No exemplo acima eu só li o número do apartamento e passei para o construtor, mas no seu caso basta modificar este trecho para ler todos os dados que precisa, e depois crie um construtor na classe `Apartamento` que já recebe todos esses dados (veja mais em "[*Para que serve um construtor?*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052)")

Para percorrer os apartamentos do prédio, seria algo assim:

```
for (Apartamento[] aptos : predio.getApartamentos()) {
    for (Apartamento apto : aptos) {
        System.out.println(apto.getNumero()); // acesse os demais dados do apto
    }
}
```

Comment: mt obrigado mano !!!

Comment: No caso esse adicionarApto irá permitir que só seja adicionado o mesmo número de andares para a qtd de apartamento seria isso?

Comment: @JoaoSpirit Nesse código eu assumi a premissa que todos os andares tem a mesma quantidade de apartamentos. Se quiser que cada andar tenha uma quantidade diferente, terá que ler as quantidades andar por andar.

Comment: opa mano você poderia me ajudar com mais uma dúvida? Eu estou pensando em uma maneira de não precisar o usuario colocar o numero de cada apartamento e sim ir adicionando de maneira automatica ex: ele definiria um numero ex: 100, e então a quantidade, e então a posição 0 seria 100, a posição 1 seria 101 é possível?

Comment: @JoaoSpirit Sim, daria pra fazer algo como `int numero = andar * 100 + apto` (em vez de `numero = scanner.nextInt()`). Assim, no primeiro andar você teria 100, 101, 102, no segundo andar 200, 201, 202, etc.

Comment: mt obrigado mano, eu tentei imprimir ele utilizando um sysout porém tive esse resultado: Predio [nome=null, aptos=[[Lmodel.Apartamento;@7ba4f24f, [Lmodel.Apartamento;@3b9a45b3]], mesmo tendo feito um to string no model predio e no apt.

Comment: @JoaoSpirit `aptos` é um array, então ou vc percorre ele com `for` e imprime um apartamento de cada vez (como o exemplo que tem na resposta), ou vc pode fazer `Arrays.deepToString(aptos)` (lembrando que a classe `Apartamento` deve ter seu próprio método `toString()` também).

Comment: Outra dica é: se tiver mais dúvidas específicas, mesmo que relacionadas, *talvez* seja o caso de fazer outra pergunta (mas faça uma busca no site antes, pra ver se já não existe algo parecido). É que perguntas novas ficam visíveis para todos os usuários na página principal (o que aumenta as chances de uma resposta), já aqui nos comentários menos gente vai ver (e como daqui a pouco vou desligar, diminui as suas chances de ter uma resposta) :-)